# helm use variable file for ech env

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to use multiple file for each env, for example `env/values.dev.yml` or `env/values.prd.yml`.

```yaml
# env/values.dev.yml
host: toto
```

```yaml
# env/values.prd.yml
host: titi
```

```yaml
# deployment.yml
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx:latest
          env:
          - name: val
            value: env-{{ printf "env/values.%s.yaml" .Values.host| .Files.Get | indent 12 }}
```

The output with this command :

```
$ helm template char . -f env/values.dev.yaml | grep value
value: env-
```

I get the value empty, but I expect

```
value: env-toto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use

```yaml
value: env-{{ .Values.host }}
```

because you are passing extra values explicitly.

Values, supplied after `-f` option, will be merged with `values.yaml` of your chart and overwrite overlapping keys, so there is no needed to add some extra logic to load same file.